# Changing background color of Bootstrap panel body using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap Panel and I managed to set the opacity of the body.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background:none;">
   <div class="panel-heading">What is needed to perform activity?</div>
       <div class="panel-body" id="needsBody">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
```

using the css as follow

```
#needsBody {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) !important;
}
```

I want to set this the color dynamically using jquery(or javascript) doing it as follow although it doesnt work.

```
$("#needsBody").css("background", "rgba(175, 201, 99, 0.2) !important;");
```

How would I go about in doing this effectively?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `!important`?

Comment: You have a semicolon `;` in your css property

Comment: jQuery `.css()` method doesn't handle `!important` statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery ignores the `!important` declaration as it's simply unnecessary - an element's `style` attribute (which is what jQuery sets) has higher specificity than CSS can apply (unless your CSS is riddled with `!important` declarations itself, which is bad practice for this exact reason). Drop the `!important` and it will work fine:

```
$("#needsBody").css("background", "rgba(175, 201, 99, 0.2)");
```

For this to work you'll need to remove the `!important` from your existing styling:

```css
#needsBody {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

If that fails to apply the style, simply increase its specificity by improving your selector's strength: `div.panel-body#needsBody { ... }`, for instance.

Comment: Still have `!important` statement in CSS rule

Comment: @A.Wolff I'd accidentally edited that out of my answer it seems (as a paragraph was missing, making it very confusing to read!). I've added it back in.

Comment: Sorry, i meant OP is using in CSS: `#needsBody {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) !important;
}` I guess he could just remove the `!important` statement from here too

Comment: @A.Wolff ah, I hadn't noticed that at all! I'll add that in now.

Comment: I removed the !important rule and now it fine...excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Try using hex instead.  It worked for me.

```
$("#needsBody").css("background", "#AFC963");
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property should be `background-color` and the `!important` is not needed here. Also, you have a semicolon in your CSS property.

Try with:

$("#needsBody").css("background-color", "rgba(175, 201, 99, 0.2)");